# Selenium to test Page without opening the page again

Tags: unit-testing, jsf, selenium, primefaces

I have a requirement where I want to test the below scenario with Selenium:

1. Open the xhtml page and the value in the datatable is 10.
2. Change the value in the database from 10 to 20
3. Click on the refresh button(Without opening the same xhtml page again) and value should be 20 now.

Below is what I am doing. But no success..

```
@Test
    @InSequence(1)
    public void addTestData() {
        Warp.initiate(new Activity() {
            @Override
            public void perform() {
                OurPage page = OurPage.on(selenium).withPath(SetupTestData.PATH);
                page.addTestDataFor(REFRESH_SHOULD_WORK);
            }
        }).inspect(new Inspection() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        });
    }

    @InSequence(2)
    @Test
    public void refreshShouldWork() {

        Warp.initiate(new Activity() {
            @Override
            public void perform() {
                CountryDetailsPage page = new CountryDetailsPage(selenium).withPath(CountryDetailsPage.PATH);

                page.open();

                System.out.println("*** PAGE OPENED ****");

                waitGui().until().element(page.table(PROGRESSES_TABLE)).is().present();

                assertThat(page.table.row(FIRST).cell(FIFTH).text(), is("10"));

                // FIXME: Need to find out the way to change the value
                page.refresh().click();

                System.out.println("*** CLICKED REFRESH ****");

                waitGui().until().element(page.table(PROGRESSES_TABLE)).is().present();

                assertThat(page.table.row(FIRST).cell(FIFTH).text(), is("20"));

            }
        }).inspect(new Inspection() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @AfterPhase(RENDER_RESPONSE)
            public void beforeRenderResponse() {
                System.out.println("*** AFTER  RENDER RESPONSE****");
            }

            @AfterPhase(Phase.APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES)
            public void afterRenderResponse() {
                System.out.println("*** AFTER APPLY REQUEST VALUES ****");
            }
        });
    }
```

If you have any idea how can I achieve this, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Being that Selenium automates only the UI, you should let a different technology handle the database.  Selenium by itself is unable to connect to any database and change what you want.

You can use Java to do this.  More specifically, use Java Database Connectivity (JDBC).

Here's an example that [Vogella uses](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/MySQLJava/article.html)

```
  try {
      // this will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      // setup the connection with the DB.
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
              + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");

      // statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
      statement = connect.createStatement();
      // resultSet gets the result of the SQL query
      resultSet = statement
          .executeQuery("select * from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
      writeResultSet(resultSet);

      // preparedStatements can use variables and are more efficient
      preparedStatement = connect
          .prepareStatement("insert into  FEEDBACK.COMMENTS values (default, ?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");
      // "myuser, webpage, datum, summary, COMMENTS from FEEDBACK.COMMENTS");
      // parameters start with 1
      preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
      preparedStatement.setString(2, "TestEmail");
      preparedStatement.setString(3, "TestWebpage");
      preparedStatement.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(2009, 12, 11));
      preparedStatement.setString(5, "TestSummary");
      preparedStatement.setString(6, "TestComment");
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

      ...

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
      close();
    }

  }
```

Update the above code to update the actual mysql field, and you'll be golden.  Though I don't think this is a good test, as again, the UI should be making the change and Selenium should be detecting it.  This might be a good candidate for an integration test. Not a Selenium test.

Comment: I think it is perfectly valid to change data via non-ui and then assert the new behaviour via the UI.   It is faster and decouples the UI from itself. I think your opening line is a dangerous generalization

Comment: *I edited my question, it was off-point anyway.* I don't believe I am not incorrect in my assertion that UI testing should be testing the UI, not the service.  By testing to make sure that the value changed, and it reflected in the UI, you are testing the service.  You *should* test functional areas. For example, the way to CHANGE that via the UI. Also, I said "should". doesn't mean they have to abide by conventions.  Additionally, I did *answer* the question ;)

Comment: How would you test a simple app which had an input page to enter any string value and an output page which displays everything which has been input so far and has pagination and performs some other processing on the values extracted. Therefore the tests to for the input page are small.  Once you have proven the page allows you to input a string value only and that is persisted, there isn't much else to test.  However, for the output page, I need many inputs to test pagination, string processing etc..  Would you create every input the UI? Generating data via an API or DB woudl surely make sense

Comment: Oh well, this is opinion based. But personally I would keep UI testing separate from API/DB calls (the actual testing bit, it's okay for me to use API/DB in setups/cleanups). I'd rather test API/DB separately first without mixed up and tangled together with UI testing. UI testing is too fragile with high maintaining cost. So my point here is that do API/DB testing first. After that, if it is really necessary to test UI, try focus on UI only without involving API/DB tests, because they should have been done already. One vote up.

Comment: We are making the same point; it is ok to use API to set up and tear down. Testing the API is always seperate. I thought that Capsalot was saying that even set up should be done via the front end?